# Arranging WPF ListItems from left to right

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to get list items to stack from left to right as oppose to top to bottom.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="454" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="943">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3.0"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>   
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,3,3"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Machine Name:" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mname}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PartName}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I can only seem to get them to stack on top of each other. Any of the alignments I change seems to generally have no effect.

I have tried wrapping a `Grid` around the `StackPanel` with `FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` but I have only been able to get the list items to be directly in the center of the window, or on the left stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListBox
    ...
    >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: StackPanel will also flow the controls right to left if you specify RightToLeft, I believe.

Comment: But that `StackPanel` is inside `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`, so it is the styling for the individual list items, is it not? Changing that `StackPanel` to Horizontal causes the `TextBlock`s inside to instead orientate themselves left to right instead of stacking inside the list item.

Comment: @user1438893 Ah, we both thought you were talking about a different list. I've updated my answer to address what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes thank you, this seems to work as expected. The only thing now is how would I make the list items wrap once they reach the horizontal boundary of the window? Right now it will instead scroll horizontally infinitely instead of creating a new row.

Comment: @user1438893 Funny thing -- that's exactly the example I copied for you, but I stopped and changed it to this for simplicity. I'll change it back.

Comment: @user1438893 Updated. Just use a WrapPanel instead of a StackPanel.

Comment: @Tyler Yep, RightToLeft does do that on a StackPanel (but of course it would). Very cool.

Comment: Hm, I'm messing around with the WrapPanel a bit but it is still creating a horizontal scrollbar for overflow and continuously increasing the width and never creating a new row. The ListBox also has a `Grid` around it, if that needs something set to stop the horizontal overflow.

Comment: @user1438893 Try giving the WrapPanel `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and/or `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the ListBox itself.

Comment: Ah, I actually have to put `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` inside the `<ListBox` declaration.

Comment: Well instead of starting a new question... maybe someone will know this one easily. Where I define the `ItemsContainerStyle` and have `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3.0"/>`, how would I also set the `CornerRadius`, it does not show up as an option.

Comment: @user1438893 CornerRadius is a property of Border. The items don't have it. You'd have to set the Template property in another setter. In the template, something like `<Grid><Border CornerRadius="3"><ContentPresenter /></Border></Grid>`. ContentPresenter is a magic widget that the control knows to put the content in. Once you do that though, you're replacing all the visual elements with your own -- so you'll have to bind Border.Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" etc. etc. for BorderBrush, BorderThickness, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You want `Orientation="Horizontal"`

[StackPanel.Orientation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That actually makes things worse as the `StackPanel` I have is for the items _inside_ the list item. So instead of the items inside the list item (the textblocks) stacking on top of each other, they go beside each other, but that `StackPanel` has no effect on the position of the list items themselves are far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. You probably need to set a StackPanel with the horizontal orientation as the `ItemsPanel` property on the ListBox. It may need to be in a template... It's been a while since I tried this.